# PHP: Inserting variables into template file - include() or file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, variables, templates

I'm working on a project where I'm keeping all HTML content separate from the rest of the PHP code. Each instance where any HTML needs to be parsed for PHP variables is sent through a function call. Most these deal with dynamic data from the database.

A simple example of a template file:

```
<div id='{$data['id']}'>{$data['text']}</div>
```

The variables in the $data array are passed through a function call where the HTML snippet needs to be added to the output buffer:

```
$output .= $html->load_template('template_id', array('id' => 123, 'text' => 'Testing'));
```

The html::load_template() function simply locates the correct text file, and is supposed to load the variables and return the string as HTML. This is where I'm having issues:

```
    public static function load($template, $data=array()) {
       ob_start();
       include ( TEMPLATE . $template .'.tpl' );
       ob_flush();
    }
```

I've tried using include() and file_get_contents(), but to no avail - I'm looking for a simple solution where I can use the {$data['var']} syntax, preferably retaining the template HTML as a simple variable, so it can then be added to the output.

I'm trying to avoid using eval().

Can someone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same thing in the past, you can modify your below code like this:

```
public static function load($template, $data=array()) {
    ob_start();
    include ( TEMPLATE . $template .'.tpl' );
    $getData = ob_get_clean();
    preg_match_all("|{([^>].*)}|U", $getData, $getDataArr, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    if (is_array($getDataArr) && count($getDataArr) > 0) {
        foreach ($getDataArr as $php) {
            if (strpos($php[1],'$') !== false) {
                $getData= str_replace($php[0], (eval('return $'.str_replace('$', '', $php[1]).';')), $getData);
            }
        }
    }

    echo $getData;
}
```